# Accessing item in a javascript object

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

```
> var b = { a: '1' }
> b['a']
'1'
> { a:'1' }['a'] 
[ 'a' ]
> {}['a']
[ 'a' ]
> {c:2}['a']
[ 'a' ] 

and of course 
> ({ a:1 })['a']
1
```

But I would also expect { a:1 }['a'] to return 1 or an error, why am I getting an [ 'a' ]??

Comment: `{ a : 1 }` evaluates as a block with a label inside, not as an object (At least for this particular context)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

{ a:'1' }['a'] evaluates like:

{ a:'1' };
['a'];

Comment: Yep. The reason `({a:1})['a']` works is because it evaluates the object literal inside the parentheses before trying to access the key. Otherwise it's just a series of expressions.